# Jest to Test that a Component Cleared the Session Storage

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, session-storage

I'm trying to test a component to see if I can clear the session storage. I'm using Jest to test. I have one line that doesn't want pass the test. I can't figure out how to make sure it's testing the sessionStorage is clear. I've mocked it, and the function works, but the test still fails one line. Does anyone know how to get this line to pass?

LogOutForDisagreement.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ClipboardClip from './../ClipboardClip';

const store = require('store2');

function LogOutForDisagreement(props) {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.onChange(
            props.props.user = {
                loggedIn: false,
                email: '',
                password: '',
                firstName: ''
            },
        );
        store.clearAll();   
    };
    return (
        <div id="logOutForDisagreementClipboard" className={props.className}>
            <Form className="form">
                <ClipboardClip />
                <div className="centeredPaper">
                    <p>Sorry, you must agree to our privacy policy to access the site. You must now log out and log back in to agree to the terms.</p>
                    <Button id="logOutForDisagreement" type="" onClick={handleClick}>
                        Log Out
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
export default LogOutForDisagreement;
```

Test
LogOutForDisagreement.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import LogOutForDisagreement from './LogOutForDisagreement';
import store from 'store2';

const fakeLocalStorage = (function() {
    let storage = {"firstName": "Nathaniel", "email":"exampleFirstName.exampleLastName@example.com","timeOfLogin":"1657937069720","id":"bee89ba2-da07-4712-acd2-e8236660bb13"};
  
    return {
      getItem: function(key) {
        return storage[key] || null;
      },
      setItem: function(key, value) {
        storage[key] = value.toString();
      },
      removeItem: function(key) {
        delete storage[key];
      },
      clearAll: function() {
        storage = {};
      },
      getAll() {
        return storage;
      },
    };
  })();
describe('Test the log out for disagreement button', () =>{
    beforeAll(() => {
        Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', {
          value: fakeLocalStorage,
        });
    });
    it('renders correctly enzyme and has onclick', () => {

        const { getByText } = render(<LogOutForDisagreement />);

        fireEvent.click(getByText("Log Out"));

        window.sessionStorage.clearAll();

        const allItems = window.sessionStorage.getAll();
        console.log("These are all the items in sessionStorage: " + JSON.stringify(allItems));
        console.log("These are the number of items: " + Object.keys(allItems).length);


        expect(Object.keys(allItems).length).toBe(0);
        expect(toJson(getByText)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

I get back the following:

```
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                 |   83.33 |      100 |     100 |   83.33 |
 LogOutForDisagreement.js |   83.33 |      100 |     100 |   83.33 | 19
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

So line 19 is basically `window.sessionStorage.clearAll();`, but I can't figure out how to test it. I have a few questions:

- Am I supposed to include data that I expect it to clear in the mock?
- I can clear the data, but how do I test the line `store.clearAll();` that actually does this?
- Why doesn't this line test when all the other lines in the function pass the test?

**Edit:** So, now I'm attempting to use jest-localstorage-mock, but I keep getting the following error:

```bash
 ● Test the log out for disagreement button › renders correctly enzyme and has onclick

    ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined

      85 |     //expect(sessionStorage.clear).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      86 |
    > 87 |     dispatch(action.reset());
         |     ^
      88 |     expect(sessionStorage.clear).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      89 |     expect(sessionStorage.__STORE__).toEqual({}); // check store values
      90 |     expect(sessionStorage.length).toBe(0); // or check length
```

This call is supposed to check that the store is now clear, but I still show that the line is not covered:

```
 src/components/privacyPolicyComponents     |   24.44 |        0 |   21.05 |   24.44 |
  LogOutForDisagreement.js                  |    87.5 |      100 |     100 |    87.5 | 19
```

I'm following the instructions found in the package, but I still can't figure out what's wrong.

Do I need to import the package in the test file? I can't find a way to do this. I put the updated files below:

`LogOutForDisagreement.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ClipboardClip from './../ClipboardClip';

const store = require('store2');

function LogOutForDisagreement(props) {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.onChange(
            props.props.user = {
                loggedIn: false,
                email: '',
                password: '',
                firstName: ''
            },
        );
        store.clearAll();

    };
    return (
        <div id="logOutForDisagreementClipboard" className={props.className}>
            <Form className="form">
                <ClipboardClip />
                <div className="centeredPaper">
                    <p>Sorry, you must agree to our privacy policy to access the site. You must now log out and log back in to agree to the terms.</p>
                    <Button id="logOutForDisagreement" type="" onClick={handleClick}>
                        Log Out
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LogOutForDisagreement;
```

`LogOutForDisagreement.test.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import LogOutForDisagreement from './LogOutForDisagreement';
import store from 'store2';
//import { dispatch, action, reset } from 'jest-localstorage-mock';

let props = {
  props:
  {
    user: {
      loggedIn: false,
      email: 'email@example.com',
      password: '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',
      firstName: 'FirstName'
    },
    className: "logOutForDisagreement"
  }
};

describe('Test the log out for disagreement button', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    store.setAll({ "firstName": "FirstName", "email": "email@example.com", "timeOfLogin": "1657937069720", "id": "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" });
  });


  it('renders correctly enzyme and has onclick', () => {

    const { getByText } = render(<LogOutForDisagreement id="logOutForDisagreementClipboard" className={props.className} />);

    fireEvent.click(getByText("Log Out"));

    dispatch(action.reset());
    expect(sessionStorage.clear).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(sessionStorage.__STORE__).toEqual({}); // check store values
    expect(sessionStorage.length).toBe(0); // or check length

    expect(Object.keys(allItems).length).toBe(0);

    expect(toJson(getByText)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

**Edit:**
I'm including the contents of the `index.d.ts` of store2. If you would like to see the full package, it's on the npm registery: https://www.npmjs.com/package/store2/v/2.13.2. I also updated the last files above, and have included the configuration for `jest-localstorage-mock`, but I'm still getting an error about dispatch not defined, but I can get the error to go away when I add `store` before `dispatch`, so it's `store.dispatch`, but then I get another error about action not being defined. I figured out how to define `action`, but then I got an error about `reset` that I couldn't get to go away.

`index.d.ts`

```js
export interface StoredData {
  [key: string]: any;
}
export type Replacer = (key: any, value: any) => string | String[] | number[];
export type Reviver = (key: string, value: any) => any;
export type EachFn = (key: any, data: any) => false | any;
export type TransactFn = (data: any) => any | undefined;

type BaseSet = (key: any, data: any) => any;
type BaseGet = (key: any) => any;
type BaseSetAll = (obj: Object) => StoredData;
type BaseGetAll = () => StoredData;
type BaseTransact = (fn: EachFn, value?: any) => StoredData;
type BaseClear = (clear: false) => StoreBase;
export type Base = BaseSet & BaseGet & BaseSetAll & BaseGetAll & BaseTransact & BaseClear;

export interface StoreAPI {
  clear(): StoreBase;
  clearAll(): StoreBase;
  each(callback: EachFn): StoreBase;
  get(key: any, alt?: any|Reviver): any;
  getAll(fillObj?: StoredData): StoredData;
  has(key: any): boolean;
  isFake(force?: boolean): boolean;
  keys(fillList?: string[]): string[];
  namespace(namespace: string, noSession?: true): StoreType;
  remove(key: any, alt?: any|Reviver): any;
  set(key: any, data: any, overwrite?: boolean|Replacer): any;
  setAll(data: Object, overwrite?: boolean|Replacer): StoredData;
  add(key: any, data: any): any;
  size(): number;
  transact(key: any, fn: TransactFn, alt?: any|Reviver): StoreBase;
  area(id: string, area: Storage): StoreBase
}

export type StoreBase = StoreAPI & Base;

export type StoreType = StoreBase & {
  local: StoreBase;
  session: StoreBase;
  page: StoreBase;
};

declare const store: StoreType
export default store
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.4.22"
  },
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  }
}
```

`setupTests.js`

```js
require('jest-localstorage-mock');
```

Comment: If you're still interested in this, please include the code for module `store2`. If you solved the problem, then post your solution here.

Comment: Hey @JESii, 

Thank you for responding. I'm still interested, and I haven't solved it. I use `store2`. It's an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/store2. I'm using 2.13.2. It's got a lot of files, so I'll leave what I see in the `index.d.ts` of the package. 

Thank you

Comment: I'll see what I can do; I'm working on this stuff myself and will post what I learn.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW @Sandog, I tried the approach you're using and could not get it to work, although my use case is a bit different than yours. When a user selects a different portfolio, we clear the (graphQL) cache so that the new portfolio has a clean slate to work with (all the data changes). So for my test, all I needed to do was set things up and make sure that the `client.resetStore()` function was actually called. I did it like this:

```
 it('responds to ribbonName clicks', async () => {
    // setup the mocked resetStore() and test it.
    // Things didn't work as expected sometimes 
    // so I wanted to make sure it was setup properly :=))
    const mockResetStore = jest.fn();
    client.resetStore = mockResetStore;
    expect(mockResetStore).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    // setup and issue the call the EntityRibbon component
    const myInitialState = {...initialState};
    myInitialState.entitiesList.push(...testEntities);
    const providerValue = {state: myInitialState, dispatch: () => {}};
    await render(
      <AppContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
        <EntityRibbon />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );

    // Another check to make sure the mock is working correctly
    expect(mockResetStore).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    // find and click the portfolio names on the EntityRibbon
    R.pluck('ribbonName', testEntities).forEach(async ribbonName => {
      const ribbonElement = await screen.getByText(ribbonName);
      expect(ribbonElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      await fireEvent.click(ribbonElement);
      // Ensure that client.resetStore() was actually called as expected
      expect(client.resetStore).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
 })
```

Maybe that'll help...

Comment: I got store undefined. I tried to strip it down to what I thought were essentials. I removed the store import and got the following error:
```ReferenceError: store is not defined```
Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: First off, you'll need to continue to import store, as you're using that in the code. You could write one test where you overwrite only the clearAll() function like `store.clearAll() = jest.fn()`, then make sure that function was invoked with `expect(store.clearAll).toHaveBeenCalled()` -- did you try something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I makes the test fail for more lines. The error says that the left side of the equation is incorrect.